# storing the files in a web application in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file

I have set of components that i wish to let the users download from my web application. 
Now the question is where should i place the files in app_data or create a separate folder in asp.net web application as shown [here](http://postimage.org/image/yryfv5k4/) or is there any other optimal solution for this ?

What i mean by components is you can take a look at [this](http://postimage.org/image/mbx230zo/) ! So what is the best way to do store the components ?

Right now what i'm doing is: i'm storing the files in a external folder outside the application more specifically in documents folder of my c drive, and i'm storing the path to a component as a data element of the table, when ever user clicks on a particular row's button (in the grid view) i'm getting the title of that particular clicked row and querying the database table for the filepath of that component title using these lines of code:

```
String filePath = dr1[0].ToString(); //GETS THE FILEPATH FROM DATABASE
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
String disHeader = "Attachment; Filename=\"" + filePath + "\"";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);
System.IO.FileInfo fileToDownload = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(fileToDownload.FullName);
```

Am i doing it properly ? Is there a better/optimal way to do it ?

Comment: `app_data` is for file based databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user simply needs read access to download a file, so you can simply create a directory claled "Downloads" and place them in there.

You can ensure that people can't "browse" that directory by disabling Directory Browsing and not placing any default docs in there (index.html, default.aspx for example)

Answer (score 1):

What you are currently doing looks like a fairly standard way for providing downloads off your site.

I can't think of something more "optimal".